# useIonViewWillEnter not working as expected - Ionic, ReactJS, Context API

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-context

I have a screen in my app which uses Context API reducers to fetch data from server on load. For this i have setup the code as follows. This is a functional component.

```
const refreshView = () => {
    propertyDispatch({
      type: "GETPROPERTYS",
      mobileNumber: contextValue.mobileNumber,
    });
  };

  useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    refreshView();
  });


<IonContent fullscreen>
          {console.log({ render: propertyState })}
          {propertyState.properties! && (
            <IonGrid>
              {propertyState.properties!.map((property: any) => (
                <IonRow key={property.propertyID}>
                  <IonCol>
```

Reducer

```
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GETPROPERTYS": {
          propertyservices.getPropertys(action.mobileNumber).then((response) => {
            let propes = [...response.data[0]];
            console.log(props);
            newData.properties = [];
            propes.map((p) => {
              let property = {};
              property.name = p.PropertyName;
newData.properties.push(property);
```

I have verified that my dispatch method is working fine. However the newly created array is blank in the view's return method. Whats more weird is if I console log propertyState I can see one record in the array, but if I console log propertyState.properties, I cannot see anything.

console.log(propertyState)
[image]
console.log(propertyState.properties)
[image]